# Why I can not add Gradle dependency by the Generate context menu in IntlliJ Idea IDE

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Today I refer to [Add a Gradle dependency](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.1/work-with-gradle-dependency-diagram.html#add_gradle_dependency) section to add Gradle dependency by the Generate context menu. Unfortunately, I encounter some trouble. When I press ⌘N to open the Generate context menu in my Idea. It show like below [image]. In the  Add a Gradle dependency tutorials, it show like below [image]. So how can I get the windows like the Add a Gradle dependency tutorials showing.

Comment: My IntelliJ Idea Version is 2021.1.3  Ultimate Edition same to the tutorials

Comment: I think the 'add Maven artifact dependency' is only available for `build.gradle` scripts, while you have a `build.gradle.kts` script.

Comment: Thanks. It works, when I change to use build.gradle scirpts.  I wonder if I use build.gradle.kts script,  how can I add dependency like  Add a Gradle dependency tutorials showing. Is there some way to achieve that.

Comment: You can do it only manually. Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-12831/Gradle-Kotlin-DSL-Generate-support-Add-Gradle-plugin-Add-Maven-artifact-dependency-options